# Как в npm передать переменную окружения взятую из файла (windows cmd)

Tags: cmd, npm, orm, .env

Работаю с npm и в один из скриптов запуска пытаюсь передать переменную окружения взятую из файла `.env.development` (соответственно для прода будет `.env.production`)
В `.env.development` лежит переменная `DB_URL=pg:\\pg:5432`
Я хочу прочитать этот env файл, найти переменную `DB_URL` и записать ее в переменную окружения
(Если кому-то интересно почему все так сложно, то это связано с работой с prisma orm, которая не умеет в `schema.prisma` динамически подгружать переменный из разных env файлов, у нее есть строгая ссылка только на `.env` в корне, что лишает возможности иметь разные env файлы для разных сред разработки - dev и prod)

Итак, я пытаюсь запустить `npm run migrate:dev` и вот все что я смог придумать:

```
"migrate:dev": "set ENV=type .env.development && \"%ENV%\" (set /p DB_URL=) && npm run migrate:dev"

""%ENV%"" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, Вы задали мне верное направление, я нашел конкретное решение для моей проблемы https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/development-environment/environment-variables/using-multiple-env-files